# Assign multiple outputs from a MATLAB function to a VBA array

Tags: matlab, vba, com, com-automation

I have a matlab function structured such that:

```
function[foo,bar] = MyMatlabFunction(varargin)
```

I call this function from VBA code thus:

```
Dim ML as Object
Set ML = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
varargout = ML.Execute("MyMatlabFunction(varargin)")
```

This works fine, however I am only able to access the output 'foo' using this method. How do I assign another variable to get 'bar' as well? i.e. how do I write:

```
[varargout1, varargout2,... varargoutn] = ML.Execute("MyMatlabFunction.m")
```

Thank you!

Comment: why the downvote, this is a valid question. @Pooja_Parthasarathy: have you tried using [`Feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/com.feval.html)?